# AWS ElastiCache Redis node instance type vs. EC2 instance type

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-elasticache

I'm looking for a list of instance details (Max bandwidth, Memory, vCPU, etc.) for ElastiCache (Redis). So far I can only find the instance information for EC2 (ex. [this doc](https://aws.amazon.com/ec2/instance-types/r5/))

I'm wondering if I can find similar page for Redis node? Or are they the same as the corresponding EC2 instance? (For example, I'm looking for the network bandwidth and vCPU for `cache.r5.xlarge`) Thanks!

Comment: They are the same as ec2, and that goes for all their managed services.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The details you are asking for(vCPU, memory etc) are listed on the pricing page of elasticache.

Here you can find the [details](https://aws.amazon.com/elasticache/pricing/)